# Error running Spring Batch application in Intellij IDEA 14.1

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-batch, tomcat6, spring-batch-admin

I get the below error while deploying my Spring Batch application (war) from IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 (Ultimate edition) into Tomcat server 6.0.26.

However, if I take the same war file and deploy it manually in Tomcat webapps, then I don't see any error. Has anyone faced this issue?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A
>   job configuration with this name [deferJob] was already registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. For some reason, IntelliJ IDEA was picking up duplicate spring batch xml files from /src/test/resources. I have raised this issue with IntelliJ support team.